# Is there any way to tell a Visual Studio post build event where the output executable of an entire build will be from a sub-project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have an application which uses a common library from my company's codebase. That common library has some dependencies which need to end up in the same directory as the application it's being used from.

My solution is laid out something like this:

```
\My solution
    \Common Project
    \Processing Library
    \Gui Application
```

Each project is set to build into `$(ProjectDir)\$(Configuration)`

I have a post-build event in the common library which does something along the following lines:

```
copy "$(Boost)\stage\lib\boost_chrono*.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

...which according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c02as0cs.aspx) (as I read it) should put it in the output directory of the current master project (i.e. the startup project)?

Maybe I'm reading it wrong but for some reason, no matter what I try, it always copies those libraries into the the Processing Library output directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: which project you add the post build event? It works for the current project, not the startup project.

Comment: The post build event is in the common library so that if it's included from other projects, those boost .dlls end up in the final output of those (or at least that's what we'd like to happen). By 'current project' do you mean the common one?

Comment: Yes, the common library project.

Comment: If that's the case then why are they ending up in the output area for the Processing Library?

Comment: VS puts the command in a batch file and runs it. You just specify the source parameter to the command copy, so it will copy to the current working directory. I think some command changes the current working dir. To fix this problem, you can simple provide the target path.

Comment: Sorry Matt; looks like my copy/paste failed - I've updated the post-build snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some experimenting and whilst it seems unlikely this is the correct way to do things, the following method does appear to work; If you manually edit the solution file and put the project you want as the `Target` to the top of the list of projects, that is the one which the `TargetDir` seems to refer to.

Previously my processing project was at the top of the list but after altering the order to put my GUI project at the top, the boost .dll's end up where I was expecting them.